Update multiple items in Dynamodb
I need realisation to update the other fields of database if one of them has been changed. For sample: if the index of one item is changed, I should update this index in other items. As I understood I can do it using loop(using query GET and then I can update each item). But there is some problem - when we update one item, dynamodb blocks only this item. When we have two requests at the same time we can't be sure that the last operation exactly correct, other words - we are not sure that our operations have correct order(first, second but not vice verse).
I've checked and tried different test cases including transactions. Transactions in dynamodb is only to revert set of operations in case when one of the operations is fail.

You should activate Streams in your table and use Triggers.
So, as soon as one item changes, you can detect that, and, for example with a Lambda Function, you can update the tables you need to.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html

It looks like you are using a non-relational DB to model relations. You might want to rethink this approach. In this case, you might want to group those items into a single one (see: Best practices for transactions).
Anyway, assuming you know which items need to have that field updated (e.g you have a list with their keys in the item that was modified), you can either:

Read that list of dependent item keys before modifying the item on which they depend, and craft a DynamoDB TransactWriteItems with all the required Update operations (source and dependent item updates). Additionally you should enable some sort of versioning mechanism in the source item, and make the update depend on the condition that the version didn't change since you read the list of dependent items.
Enable DynamoDB Stream, have a Lambda function listen to the stream, and run the above transaction only with the dependent item updates.

The first approach ensures atomicity, while the second one will achieve eventual consistency.

Please note that Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned and read Help Center: AI policy. It is not permitted to use AI tools to generate or reword content that you post on Stack Overflow.

@DarkBee Please note that I'm not generative AI. Duh...
